# Why am I getting wrong output for this query?

Tags: mysql

Question:

For each department that has more than five employees, retrieve the department number and the number of its employees who are making more than $40,000

Table Contents:

| "fname" | "minit" | "lname" | "ssn" | "bdate" | "address" | "sex" | "salary" | "superssn" | "dno" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "Jared" | "D" | "James" | "111111100" | "1966-10-10" | "123 Peachtree, Atlanta, GA" | "M" | 85000.0 | "" | 6 |
| "Jon" | "C" | "Jones" | "111111101" | "1967-11-14" | "111 Allgood, Atlanta, GA" | "M" | 45000.0 | "111111100" | 6 |
| "Justin" | "n" | "Mark" | "111111102" | "1966-01-12" | "2342 May, Atlanta, GA" | "M" | 40000.0 | "111111100" | 6 |
| "Brad" | "C" | "Knight" | "111111103" | "1968-02-13" | "176 Main St., Atlanta, GA" | "M" | 44000.0 | "111111100" | 6 |
| "John" | "B" | "Smith" | "123456789" | "1955-01-09" | "731 Fondren, Houston, TX" | "M" | 30000.0 | "333445555" | 5 |
| "Evan" | "E" | "Wallis" | "222222200" | "1958-01-16" | "134 Pelham, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 92000.0 | "" | 7 |
| "Josh" | "U" | "Zell" | "222222201" | "1954-05-22" | "266 McGrady, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 56000.0 | "222222200" | 7 |
| "Andy" | "C" | "Vile" | "222222202" | "1944-06-21" | "1967 Jordan, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 53000.0 | "222222200" | 7 |
| "Tom" | "G" | "Brand" | "222222203" | "1966-12-16" | "112 Third St, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 62500.0 | "222222200" | 7 |
| "Jenny" | "F" | "Vos" | "222222204" | "1967-11-11" | "263 Mayberry, Milwaukee, WI" | "F" | 61000.0 | "222222201" | 7 |
| "Chris" | "A" | "Carter" | "222222205" | "1960-03-21" | "565 Jordan, Milwaukee, WI" | "F" | 43000.0 | "222222201" | 7 |
| "Kim" | "C" | "Grace" | "333333300" | "1970-10-23" | "6677 Mills Ave, Sacramento, CA" | "F" | 79000.0 | "" | 6 |
| "Jeff" | "H" | "Chase" | "333333301" | "1970-01-07" | "145 Bradbury, Sacramento, CA" | "M" | 44000.0 | "333333300" | 6 |
| "Franklin" | "T" | "Wong" | "333445555" | "1945-12-08" | "638 Voss, Houston, TX" | "M" | 40000.0 | "888665555" | 5 |
| "Alex" | "D" | "Freed" | "444444400" | "1950-10-09" | "4333 Pillsbury, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 89000.0 | "" | 7 |
| "Bonnie" | "S" | "Bays" | "444444401" | "1956-06-19" | "111 Hollow, Milwaukee, WI" | "F" | 70000.0 | "444444400" | 7 |
| "Alec" | "C" | "Best" | "444444402" | "1966-06-18" | "233 Solid, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 60000.0 | "444444400" | 7 |
| "Sam" | "S" | "Snedden" | "444444403" | "1977-07-31" | "987 Windy St, Milwaukee, WI" | "M" | 48000.0 | "444444400" | 7 |
| "Joyce" | "A" | "English" | "453453453" | "1962-07-31" | "5631 Rice, Houston, TX" | "F" | 25000.0 | "333445555" | 5 |
| "John" | "C" | "James" | "555555500" | "1975-06-30" | "7676 Bloomington, Sacramento, CA" | "M" | 81000.0 | "" | 6 |
| "Nandita" | "K" | "Ball" | "555555501" | "1969-04-16" | "222 Howard, Sacramento, CA" | "M" | 62000.0 | "555555500" | 6 |
| "Bob" | "B" | "Bender" | "666666600" | "1968-04-17" | "8794 Garfield, Chicago, IL" | "M" | 96000.0 | "" | 8 |
| "Jill" | "J" | "Jarvis" | "666666601" | "1966-01-14" | "6234 Lincoln, Chicago, IL" | "F" | 36000.0 | "666666600" | 8 |
| "Kate" | "W" | "King" | "666666602" | "1966-04-16" | "1976 Boone Trace, Chicago, IL" | "F" | 44000.0 | "666666600" | 8 |
| "Lyle" | "G" | "Leslie" | "666666603" | "1963-06-09" | "417 Hancock Ave, Chicago, IL" | "M" | 41000.0 | "666666601" | 8 |
| "Billie" | "J" | "King" | "666666604" | "1960-01-01" | "556 Washington, Chicago, IL" | "F" | 38000.0 | "666666603" | 8 |
| "Jon" | "A" | "Kramer" | "666666605" | "1964-08-22" | "1988 Windy Creek, Seattle, WA" | "M" | 41500.0 | "666666603" | 8 |
| "Ray" | "H" | "King" | "666666606" | "1949-08-16" | "213 Delk Road, Seattle, WA" | "M" | 44500.0 | "666666604" | 8 |
| "Gerald" | "D" | "Small" | "666666607" | "1962-05-15" | "122 Ball Street, Dallas, TX" | "M" | 29000.0 | "666666602" | 8 |
| "Arnold" | "A" | "Head" | "666666608" | "1967-05-19" | "233 Spring St, Dallas, TX" | "M" | 33000.0 | "666666602" | 8 |
| "Helga" | "C" | "Pataki" | "666666609" | "1969-03-11" | "101 Holyoke St, Dallas, TX" | "F" | 32000.0 | "666666602" | 8 |
| "Naveen" | "B" | "Drew" | "666666610" | "1970-05-23" | "198 Elm St, Philadelphia, PA" | "M" | 34000.0 | "666666607" | 8 |
| "Carl" | "E" | "Reedy" | "666666611" | "1977-06-21" | "213 Ball St, Philadelphia, PA" | "M" | 32000.0 | "666666610" | 8 |
| "Sammy" | "G" | "Hall" | "666666612" | "1970-01-11" | "433 Main Street, Miami, FL" | "M" | 37000.0 | "666666611" | 8 |
| "Red" | "A" | "Bacher" | "666666613" | "1980-05-21" | "196 Elm Street, Miami, FL" | "M" | 33500.0 | "666666612" | 8 |
| "Ramesh" | "K" | "Narayan" | "666884444" | "1952-09-15" | "971 Fire Oak, Humble, TX" | "M" | 38000.0 | "333445555" | 5 |
| "James" | "E" | "Borg" | "888665555" | "1927-11-10" | "450 Stone, Houston, TX" | "M" | 55000.0 | "" | 1 |
| "Jennifer" | "S" | "Wallace" | "987654321" | "1931-06-20" | "291 Berry, Bellaire, TX" | "F" | 43000.0 | "888665555" | 4 |
| "Ahmad" | "V" | "Jabbar" | "987987987" | "1959-03-29" | "980 Dallas, Houston, TX" | "M" | 25000.0 | "987654321" | 4 |
| "Alicia" | "J" | "Zelaya" | "999887777" | "1958-07-19" | "3321 Castle, Spring, TX" | "F" | 25000.0 | "987654321" | 4 |

My query:

```
select dno, count(*) from EMPLOYEE where salary > 40000 group by dno having count(*) > 5
```

Output:

| dno | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 10 |

Answer:

```
SELECT dno, COUNT(*) 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Salary>40000 AND dno IN
( SELECT dno
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY dno
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5)
GROUP BY dno;
```

Output:

| dno | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 7 |
| 7 | 10 |
| 8 | 5 |

Comment: Because of when you apply your filtering, your query is getting is retrieving departments where more than 5 employees are making more than 40000 (as the `WHERE` is applied before the `COUNT(*)`), rather than where the department has more than 5 employees on any salary, then filtering to those that make more than 40000, which is what the actual answer is doing (i.e. doing the `COUNT(*)` in a separate query independent of the salary filter)

Comment: I hope this isn't real data... if it was, you should contact SO to permanently delete your question.

Comment: Given the number of consecutive/invalid SSNs I suspect that this is not real data. It also appears to be a tutorial/workshop question, so the data is probably the sample data provided for that.

Comment: Considering that the list includes "Arnold Head" and "Helgi Pataki", who are characters from the TV show *Hey Arnold!*, I'm convinced that this is just made-up data.

Comment: @DanielW. This data is given in our DBMS TextBook, so I assume they would not give real data